add a progress bar before opening a window
I have a pyqt project where there is a large file processing, when I click on a button (Browse Folder) that will open a window containing treeviews that present the hierarchy of files, the window remains white for a few seconds, so here, I want to display a progress bar (like the loading one).
Here is my code :
class StartWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Open ODL File or Folder')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('assets/acls_icon.png'))
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
        self.resize(600, 400)
    
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        buttons_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.choose_file_button = QPushButton('Browse File', self)
  
        self.choose_file_button.clicked.connect(self.choose_file)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.choose_file_button)
        
        self.choose_folder_button = QPushButton('Browse Folder', self)
   
        self.choose_folder_button.clicked.connect(self.choose_folder)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.choose_folder_button)

        main_layout.addLayout(buttons_layout)
        
    def choose_folder(self):
        folder_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Open Folder Containing ODL Files")
        if folder_path:
            self.open_folder_view(folder_path)


    def open_folder_view(self, folder_path):
        folder_window = QDialog()
        folder_window.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        folder_window.setWindowTitle('ODL Files Tree View')
        folder_window.resize(800, 600)
        folder_window.show()

        processed_files = set() 
        all_groups = set()
        self.folder_path = folder_path
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
            for filename in files:
                if (filename.endswith(".odl")) and ('acl' in filename.lower() or 'acls' in filename.lower()) and filename not in processed_files:
                    file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    parser = ODLParser(file_path)
                    file_groups, _ = get_headers_and_rights(parser.data_model)
                    all_groups.update(file_groups)
                    tree_view = self.create_tree_view(parser)
                    scroll_layout.addWidget(tree_view)
                    processed_files.add(filename)
                
                elif (filename.endswith(".odl")) and not ('acl' in filename.lower() or 'acls' in filename.lower()) and filename not in processed_files:
                    file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                        content = file.read()
                        if "acl" in content.lower() and "{" in content.lower():
                            parser = ODLParser2(file_path)
                            file_groups, _ = get_headers_and_rights(parser.data_model)
                            all_groups.update(file_groups)
                            tree_view = self.create_tree_view(parser)
                            scroll_layout.addWidget(tree_view)
                            processed_files.add(filename)
                    
        valid_groups = [group for group in all_groups if group is not None]
        self.group_combobox.addItems(sorted(valid_groups))
        self.group_combobox.setCurrentIndex(0) 
        self.group_combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_group_combobox_changed)
        QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.on_group_combobox_changed(self.group_combobox.currentText()))
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(scroll_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        folder_window.exec_()


is it possible to do it? if not, please suggest me any other idea.

The answer is a little more complicated because you're trying to skip this problem: the window is freezing. When you run code that takes a lot of time to finish running, Qt's event loop won't be processed, so the OS will think that the application has frozen. When it happens, all widgets are frozen, you can't click on stuff, and on windows, if you click too much, the OS will ask to close the application. You should worry about moving your cpu consuming task to a QThread, so it doesn't block the Qt event loop on the main thread, and only then add a QProgressBar when its all working.

Use QProgressDialog and periodically call QApplication.processEvents() (for instance, at every iteration of the outer for loop. Note that you should probably not display the dialog until it's fully laid out, so you should remove folder_window.show().
